# Exclude some items from a list with Lambda

Tags: c#, linq

I have a command to select the items from an observable collection.

```
Items.Select(a => a.MyParameter).ToList()
```

Is there a way to extend this line to say "but not MyParameter==IsBad?"

EDIT: I apologize for not asking a clearer question.

Select all of the items.MyDoubleValue but not the items that have items.Exclude==true. This goes to a list in one case and it goes to sum in another. I have to add the boolean Exclude to all of the items so I have to edit the summing, averaging, standard deviations, etc. I just wanted to avoid multi line code if I can.

Comment: what is the type for MyParameter?  if its bool then check for false or true to exclude.  Items.Select(a => a.MyParameter).Where(a => a.MyParameter == false).ToList()  would eliminate all that are false.  of if its an integer you could say MyParameter>=10 to exclude all that are less than 10

Comment: @Equalsk the select method is returning the `MyParameter` values, not `a`, so the Where would not be accessing `MyParameter` on the incoming variable, but would just be comparing the incoming variable directly to the `IsBad` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called Using Linq, and its one of my favorite features in C# because it reminds me of Python.

When you write:

```
Items.Select(a => a.MyParameter).ToList();
```

The use of the lambda/delegate syntax causes **a** to become an element of your collection, **Items**.

The elements in Items must have some parameter in it called **a.MyParameter**.  Hence, this above line of code simply grabs all of the **MyParameter** objects.

If you wanted to filter certain values of **MyParameter**, you should use **Where** instead:

```
Items.Where(a => a.MyParameter != IsBad).ToList();
```

In short, use **Select** to transform every element, but use **Where** to filter.  And if you wanted to, you could also combine both, depending on what you want in the end.

Comment: Thank you. But I did not ask my question clearly and have misled you. MyParameter is a double and the exclusion is based on another property of the item. In this case the property Exclude. so I have to have something like  
items.select(a=>a.MyDoubleValue).Where(e=>!e.Exclude).ToList(); as written by Xiaoy312 below. But that generates a compile error on the Exclude and cannot return a double value.

Comment: The items.select(a=>a.MyDoubleValue) is giving you an enumerable of doubles.  So your e variable for the where clause is working on doubles.  Do the where part first and then you could do the select part second.

Comment: So: items dot where none of my items is excluded, but dot select the doubles from my items.    Items.Where(x => !x.Exclude).Select(a => a.MyDoubleValue).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the sequence through `Where`:

```
Items
    .Select(a => a.MyParameter)
    .Where(p => !p.IsBad)
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Items.Where(a=>a.MyParameter!=IsBad).ToList();
```

Comment: Needs the original Select(a =>a.MyParameter) to return the same type as the original statement. But the filtering part looks good!